# Cannot add WCF Service to Project Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wcf

I've created an empty ASP .NET Web Application and added an ADO .NET Entity Data Model which, at a later moment, I'd like to access via a WPF client. However whenever I'm trying to add an WCF Service to my project im greeted with the error:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Does someone have any solutions?

EDIT:
I've deployed my project on the local IIS and when I try to navigate to my Service.svc the two tables that should be displayed are shown in a perfectly fine way, but when I navigate to one of them using this URL:

```
http://localhost/TestUE/Service1.svc/movie
```

I'm greeted with this error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code/>
<m:message xml:lang="de-AT">Fehler beim Verarbeiten dieser Anforderung.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Comment: How you are trying to add the wcf service?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a new Visual Studio 2017 update (15.5.5) fixed the issue I had with adding a new WCF Service, now it works again with no problems at all.

The second issue I had with not being able to navigate to one of my table names with the given URL has been resolved by also activating `ASP.NET Impersonation` in the authentication settings of the IIS virtual directory corresponding to my project. Then under `Edit` I chose the first available option and entered my user credentials.